# What are the consequences of "screwing up" the assignment operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I want to have double values with a name and units, but I want to use them as if they were simple doubles. For example I want to use them like this:

```
int main(){
    NamedValue a("a","m");
    NamedValue b("b","m");
    NamedValue c("c","m^2");
    a = 3;
    b = 5;
    c = a*b;
    std::cout << a << b << c <<  std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and the output should be:

```
a = 3 m
b = 5 m
c = 15 m^2
```

I came up with this solution:

```
class NamedValue  {
public:
    NamedValue(std::string n,std::string u) : name(n),units(u){}
    const std::string name;
    const std::string units;
    void operator=(double v){this->value = v;}
    void operator=(const NamedValue& v){this->value = v.value;}
    operator double() const { return value; }      
private:
    double     value;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream,const NamedValue& v) {
     stream << v.name << " = " << (double)v <<  " " << v.units << std::endl;
     return stream;
}
```

Unitl now it works nicely, but I am mainly concerned about the assignment operator `void operator=(const NamedValue& v){this->value = v.value;}` that is not exactly doing, what one normally would expect of an assignment operator.

**Are there any bad consequences that I will face?**

I am thinking about things like passing an object as parameter and stuff like that. However, a function like this

```
NamedValue test(NamedValue x){return x;}
```

works without problems, as there is no assignment involved (only copy constructor). Am I missing something? Is there anything else I should be aware of?

ps: Just in case you wonder, at the moment I do not care about checking the units when doing calculations.

Comment: Why don't you try using that assignment operator and see what happens? If you don't care that `name` and `units` aren't set, then it "works". But it does look quite strange.

Comment: @juanchopanza I tried it and it works as expected. However, I tried it for the things it was intentionally written for (i.e. in expressions like `c=a+b`) and now I wonder if there are other things that need a properly working assignment operator (ie. one that really assigns the full object and not just one field of it) that may fail.

Comment: @juanchopanza sorry, I was a bit confused: `c=a+b` actually does not use assignment operator i was talking about (but the one with `NamedValue=double`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment operator is totally fine. The only thing unusual about it is that you did not return the object so the operator calls cannot be chained. Otherwise, it's a completely normal operator.

Comment: do you mean "chained", if not, I dont understand ;)

Comment: Actually I misunderstood the rule of 3. I though "when you overload any of them you should overload all" but after consulting it again I understood that "when you **have** to overload any of them you should overload all". So it really is totally fine and the question a bit dumb ;)